# Move Channel Form Javascript to end of page

Tags: channel-form, zoo-visitor, 2.8

I need to move the javascript block that is used by the channel form module from below my form to the bottom of the page, (after my scripts).

It's says that if you want to supply jquery yourself you will need to place the script above the form. However doing this has introduced other errors.  Also I'm using my own validation methods.

Is there anyway to just append the javascript block to the bottom of my page?

I'm using Zoo Visitor

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some add-ons / field types in your Channel Form will only work if the JS is included in the head, which is unfortunate, as best-practice dictates your JS should live below the content.

I worked around this by adding a parameter in my header/footer embeds called `js_in_head`. On pages with Channel Forms, I just included my main jQuery include in the header, and not in the footer. A bit silly, but, it worked, and I could move onto the next issue.